# Join statement in hibernate criteria builder in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, join

I would like to create the following statement in Grails with `HibernateCriteriaBuilder`:

```
SELECT * FROM person p 
  JOIN person_authority pa ON p.id=pa.person_id 
  JOIN authority a ON pa.authority_id=a.id 
  WHERE a.authority IN ('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

`person_authority` is join table.

Update:

My `Person` class is:

```
class Person {

transient springSecurityService

Date dateCreated
Date lastLogin

String username
String password
String email;
boolean enabled
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    email blank:false, unique: true, email: true
    password blank: false
    lastLogin nullable:true
}

static mapping = {
    hasMany authority:Authority;
    password column: '`password`'
}

//Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
//  PersonAuthority.findAllByPerson(this).collect { it.authority } as Set
//}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}

public static def query(Map params = [:]){

    def rows = withCriteria(max:params.max,offset:params.offset){
        if(params.authorities){
            authorities{
                'in'('authority', params.authorities)
            }
        }
        order(params.column?:"id",params.order?:"asc")
        if(params.id){
            idEq (params.id as Long);
        }
        if(params.username){
            ilike "username","%"+params.username+"%"
        }
        if(params.email){
            ilike "email","%"+params.email+"%"
        }
        if(params.accountLocked){
            eq "accountLocked",Boolean.valueOf(params.accountLocked)
        }
        if(params.enabled){
            eq "enabled",Boolean.valueOf(params.enabled)
        }
        if(params.passwordExpired){
            eq "passwordExpired",Boolean.valueOf(params.passwordExpired)
        }
    }
    return rows;
}
}
```

Criteria I want to build is in method query. When I try to execute it I get `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.authorities() is applicable for argument types ...`

Comment: `PersonAuthority.findAllByAuthority(Authority.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN").person`

Comment: Is it possible to make this query in HibernateCriteriaBuilder because I want to attach dynamically some restrictions (like eqId etc).

Comment: You could split it out do that.Get all those with the role, then use your filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how exactly you've defined association, but will look like:

```
Person.withCriteria {
    authorities {
        'in'('authority', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I added class source in first post. I get missing method exception.  `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.authorities() is applicable for argument types ...

Comment: define "authority" association outside the "mapping" block (and better in plural): static hasMany = [authorities: Authority]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, I'm misreading, but it looks like you named your association `authority` not `authorities`

try:

```
def rows = withCriteria(max:params.max,offset:params.offset){
    if(params.authorities){
        authority{
            'in'('authority', params.authorities)
        }
    }
```

You didn't list your `Authority` domain class, is the param.authorities a list of Authority objects or maybe the "name" of the Authority?  If it's the Authority object, try it without the join (I haven't tried this, but I think it's correct):

```
if(params.authorities) {
  'in'('authority', parmas.authorities)
}
```

If it's a list of names (and Authority has a `name` field):

```
if(params.authorities){
    authority{
        'in'('name', params.authorities)
    }
}
```